# Amazon ec2 instances loopback two Network interfaces backtoback

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working application called Intel DPDK `18.05` on Amazon ec2 instance, I tried to send traffic from eth1(apart from management network) to eth2 created on my Instance.

the eth1 IP address is like `172.31.17.214` and the eth2 IP address is like `172.31.17.20`,

My problem is I need to send multiple packets from source interface eth1 to destination eth2 like 
`(172.31.17.214,.215,.216..., to 172.31.17.20)` but it is working for only `172.31.17.214` to `172.31.17.20`.

How we need to make this work for multiple ip addresses in Amazon ec2 instance?

Thanks,
Darshan

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate more IP addresses from the Amazon EC2 interface first. A guide on how to do that you can find [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html).

After that, you can add those interfaces with interface aliases:

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and add the following:

```
auto etho0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address another_ip_address
netmask netmask #must be same as eth0's netmask
```

Or if you want another ip address just for the same session, you can use `ifconfig`:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 ip_address up
```

Comment: How to associate more IP address from the Amazon EC2 interface?

Comment: @AdarshaVerma here is an amazon guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html